# Facebook - Count # of friends that a friend has

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have found multiple questions asking the same thing, but can't seem to find an answer.

I can correctly pull the friends of a user, but is there anyway to just see how many friends that friend has? I don't care for any of their info, only the number of friends they have.

Example:
My Friends
 - John Doe (has 56 friends
 - Susan Doe (has 132 friends)

Answer (score 1):

For this you should have the permission to access the friend's friend list.You first add this permission in your application.see
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ for permissions.Once you got the permission, by using https://graph.facebook.com/friend_id/friends&access_token=xxxx you will get friends count of a friend.

Answer (score -1):

```
select name,friend_count from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())
```